# vim: combine :g with command which uses range

Tags: vim

I have a text which is made of lines and some of them look like that:

> A test1
>   test test
>   test test
>
> A test2
>   test test
>   test test

The line starts with `A` (arbitrary but unique string) and ends with an empty line. 
I like to remove all redundant newline symbols from the *real* lines (without affecting other lines, not matching the `/^A/`) and make the lines look like that:

> A test1 test test test test
>
> A test2 test test test test

Once I'm at `/^A/`, I can use the command `:.,/^$/-2s/\n/ /` (range `.,/^$/-2` applied to `:s///`). Going over the whole file and doing it manually is rather mundane thus I have attempted to combine that with `:g/^A/`:

```
:g/^A/.,/^$/-2s/\n/ /
```

But that produced error since in command after `:g//`, the range wasn't recognized. I have tried to use `normal` too - `:g/^A/normal .,/^$/-2s/\n/ /` and `:g/^A/exe 'normal .,/^$/-2s/\n/ /'` - with no luck.

Is there any way to run from under `:g//` a command with range? Or is there any other easy (== without scripting) way to accomplish the same formatting task?

Comment: What vim version? Your `g/^A/.,/^$/-2s/\n/ /` works as expected (but only if blank `^$` line occurs before end of file). And do not use normal here: `normal .,/^$/-2s/\n/ /` means: `.` repeat last modification; `,` repeat last inline character search in opposite direction; `/^$/-2` search for blank lines, got two lines up, other stuff is considered a part of search command and ignored.

Comment: @ZyX: ... trying to wrap my head around it. It definitely didn't worked yesterday under VIM 6.4 and 7.2. Probably I have mistyped yesterday something and today when posting the question I have accidentally fixed it. Anyway, the response from @ar is shorter and simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. To enter the `^M`, use ctrl-v enter.

```
:g/^A/normal V/^$/^MkJ
```

Comment: It works. Can you please also explain the magic? It appears that after `normal` goes something similar to a macro.

Comment: OK. Found it myself under *surprise* `:h :normal`: `This makes it possible to execute Normal mode commands typed on the command-line. {commands} is executed like it is typed.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe:

```
:g/^A/normal JJ
```

Comment: This only deals with three line blocks.

Answer (score 0):

combining :g with commands that take a range works for me.  e.g.

```
:g/^A/.,/^$/-1join
```

as does your original version:

```
:g/^A/.,/^$/-2s/\n/ /
```

N.B. If you want brevity then the join command can be abbreviated to j, so the first version becomes:

```
:g/^A/.,/^$/-1j
```